# How to send a post request and manage loading state with riverpod 2.0

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am trying to implement a very basic loading state.
During initState, sending a post request with some parameters. And want to show a loading state on UI during I got a result (success, or failure)

I can not understand how to use build() method and AsyncLoading() together. Also the return type of the provider and build method.

This is the provider I am trying to use:
I think I am missing something very similar, however can not find any example of such a case that the build method take parameters.
If this was a get method, there is an example.

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  Future.microtask(
    () async => ref.watch(wOListProvider.notifier).getWoList(widget.woNumber),
  );
```

```
@riverpod
class WOList extends _$WOList {
  @override
  FutureOr<List<WorkOrder>?> build() async {
    return null;
  }

  List<WorkOrder> _woList = [];

  Future<void> getWoList(int woNumber) async {
    state = const AsyncLoading();
    final result = await woListRepo.getWoList(wo: woNumber);

    switch (result) {
      case Success():
        _woList = result.value.map((wo) => wo.toEntity()).toList();
        state = AsyncData(_woList);
      case Failure():
        state = AsyncError(
          result.exception.message,
          StackTrace.current,
        );
    }
  }
```

What is the best practice for such a usage?

when build method returns null, state is not AsyncLoading anymore, and loading state is lost.

Comment: Stop building things before you need them!  It looks like you want a family FutureProvider.  Use that instead.  When build() (or the create callback) finishes, it should have a useful value, not null.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I do not know what kind of provider I am using, I am using the code generation style as stated on documentation ( riverpod 2.x) , and according to the docs I do not need to care about it because generator decides what to use. So please let me know if you have any idea about code generated solution.

Comment: In codegen, you indicate a family provider with either more arguments to the function (in generated function) or more arguments to build() (in generated class).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `FutureFamilyProvider` to handle api calls with parameter.

```dart
@riverpod
FutureOr<List<WorkOrder>> woList(WoListRef ref, {required int woNumber}) async {
  final woListRepo = ref.watch(woListRepoProvider);
  final result = await woListRepo.getWoList(wo: woNumber);
  return result;
}

// Consume the provider
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  final woList = ref.watch(woListProvider(woNumber: woNumber));
  return woList.when(
    data: ...,
    error: ...,
    loading: ...,
  );
}
```

You can visit the docs here.
https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/passing_args

Comment: There are other methods in the provider to filter the list, so I am using a class instead of a function type provider. 
Or do you think, should I create a new filteredListProvider and chain these the providers?

Comment: yes you could use a class provider instead of functional provider if you need methods to mutate the state. The important thing is you should initialise your provider inside the `build` method, not returning null and then initialise it in `initState`.

To implement a filter mechanism, I usually have a listProvider, a filterProvider and a filteredListProvider, I found it is simpler this way.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is this:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ref.watch(wOListProvider.notifier).getWoList(widget.woNumber);

  final AsyncValue<List<WorkOrder>?> wOListAsync = ref.watch(wOListProvider);;

  // + check for null or use List<WorkOrder> in the state

  return switch (wOListAsync) {
      AsyncData(:final value) => ListView(
          children: [
            for (final workOrder in value)
              ListTile(
                title: Text(workOrder.toString()),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      AsyncError(:final error) => Text('Error: $error'),
      _ => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    };
  }
}
```

Or use `when`/`map` instead of switch expression to parse the AsyncValue state.

---

Also, you should store the current list in your `WOList` state, and not as a separate variable. Moreover, use `.family` (just make an argument in the notifier's `build` method) to receive this argument directly from the widget when `watch`ing.

Comment: .getWoList() is not returning anyting in my provider class. I can not understand your suggestion.

Comment: I was confused that your method is called `getWoList`... I have corrected the code in the example, but I recommend paying attention to the comments at the very end of my answer. Use `family` for your provider.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answers above, here is the simplest answer and implementation I discovered.

https://codewithandrea.com/articles/data-mutations-riverpod/